# Why use bytes instead of words for offsets in 'lw' and 'sw' instructions?

Tags: computer-architecture, assembly, mips

In assembly language, there are instructions like 'lw' (load word) and 'lb' (load byte). Both of these instructions involve adding an offset to a base address. It seems counterintuitive, however, that the offset in 'lw' and 'sw' (store word) instructions represents the number of bytes to move forward rather than indicating the number of words.

For instance, we know that when dealing with 'lw' or 'sw' that we're working with words so naturally we move forward by 4 bytes (since a word is typically 4 bytes). Why isn't the offset in 'lw' and 'sw' instructions based on the number of words we want to move forward, which would align with our intent of loading or storing words? Instead, it's based on bytes. Can someone clarify the reasoning behind this design choice?

Comment: I think this question would do better over at SO. Read up on *packed structures* and *misaligned access*.

Comment: Then why there is an assembly category and a MIPS category and a comp-arch category? Is my qeuestion unrelated to this categories?

Comment: Tags can be created by just about anyone, and there is little "moderation" on them. I guess there would be little agreement if there was. I think your question marginally related to programming as welcome on Electrical Engineering@SE: programming controllers/device drivers. Think about "register" addresses of, say, a hard disc controller.

Comment: @EmadKheyroddin The DEC Alpha only processed entire words at a time. No byte access to memory. Some allow byte access but ordering within words vary. Other processor designers make still other trade-off choices. Do you expect a bright line answer to this question?

Comment: @periblepsis what is a "bright line answer"?

Comment: @jonathanjo It's an English phrase. It just means "some clearly defined rule that leaves no room for interpretation or nuance." That's all.

Comment: @periblepsis ah yes thanks, found it at OED.  Seems it's mostly a US phrase, I'd never heard it before, certainly not common in England.

Comment: @jonathanjo What phrase, of similar meaning, is common in England?

Comment: @periblepsis perhaps "black and white answer" or "clearly-defined answer".

Comment: What if you want to read or write a misaligned word in your code? If your lw & sw only support accesses to aligned words then you'd have to perform multiple lb or sb for this operation instead of using lw or sw and letting the memory management or bus hardware figure it out for you.

Comment: @jonathanjo Hmm. We have that in the US, too. Just not quite the same sharp meaning, I guess. But thanks. I like phrases that have special meaning... not just in English. For example, "If wishes were horses, then beggars would ride" is to me not nearly so good as the Latin "if my grandmother had wheels she'd be a bicycle." (Spanish: *"Si mi abuela tuviera ruedas sería bicicleta."*) Thanks!

Comment: @brhans indeed you're correct.  Compilers take two approaches if the bus can't do misaligned fetches: 1) align everything, 2) use more code.  Typically you can specify you want padding (extra space for alignment) or packing (more code for smaller space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One typical reason for this design choice is to simplify the effective address calculator circuit.

- If the offset is always in the same units, it doesn't have to know the size of the unit being fetched.  The typical case is with byte-addressed memory having an offset measured in bytes.
- If the offset sometimes needed multiplying by say 2 or 4, we'd need some circuitry to do this, with an input from the portion of the opcode decoder which knows the unit size.  As any assembler or compiler can easily multiply all the constants before use, many CPU designers consider the gain to be negligible.

To be precise, this is a property of the machine code rather than the assembly language.

You don't say what CPU you're thinking about, which is vital as this varies enormously depending on the CPU and the memory architecture.

On the VAX for example you can access any length (eg 32-bit) at any (possibly misaligned) byte address, and the displacements are in bytes; even though on there is scaling for autoincrement/decrement, it's not done for offsets.  On TI 34010 you can access on bit addresses.  On some memory systems you'd get a bus error.  Some CPUs can have 8-, 16-, 32-bit buses and behave differently on them.  Some CPUs (DEC Alpha) only do whole 32-bit fetches.

Most modern CPUs tend towards RISC, and leave out things like scaling offsets.

---

PS.  Be aware that "word" is sometimes used to mean specifically 16-bits (68000, for example) and sometimes used to mean "joined-up bits of appropriate size" (typical computer science texts).

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays most microprocessors use eight (8) bit bytes.  An octet is a collection of eight things.  While English-speakers prefer to use byte, some non-English speakers prefer octet (recall that the French avoid using "computer" and prefer "ordinateur", which means to order things, as in sorting a list of names).  The first definition of the ASCII code used seven (7) bits and had lowercase and uppercase letters. Earlier codes, such as French BAUDOT (from which we borrowed "Baud" rate) used five (5) bits and lacked lowercase letters.  I still remember writing BASIC programs in the 70's with a Teletype brand teleprinter machine (also known as tty) with a keyboard, a printer with a roll of paper, and a tape punch and reader, connected with an acoustic coupler (at 110 Baud) via the telephone line to nearby Bentley College's computer center.  The Teletype brand teleprinter used seven (7) bits per character but it lacked lowercase letters.

Please see the following link for more information regarding these matters.

[link](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp) ASCII code

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code) Baudot code

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33) TTY

Going back to the issue, memory storage uses bytes so, it is only natural to refer to offsets as a given integer number of bytes.  It is possible to "align" the starting point of your data array on a boundary that is more appropriate to serve your purpose, such as an address that is a multiple of 16 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits or whatever amount is more convenient for your purpose.  However, if the offsets were not expressed in bytes, porting an assembly language written for a given microprocessor architecture to another one would require you to carefully review the exact meaning of the offset, lest the original architecture be one that interprets offsets as appropriate for addresses that are multiples of 16 bits but the new architecture be one that interprets them as appropriate for multiples of 32 bits.  Confusion can be avoided by forcing offsets to be expressed as an integer amount of bytes.

To quote the original answer:

So, if there is no clear definition of exactly how many bits are needed to compose a "word", the best way to define the offset to a base address is the use of the universally accepted byte made of eight (8) bits. By using bytes for the offset you cannot go wrong because the size of the byte does not depend on the manufacturer of the microprocessor, whereas the size of the "word" depends exclusively on the meaning given to it by the manufacturer of the microprocessor.

End of quote.

Granted that Intel started with a four (4) bit microprocessor and, earlier than that, various manufacturers of computers built central processing units of different numbers of bits.  But, nowadays, the basic unit of data storage is the eight (8) bit byte.  So, it is natural that offsets be expressed as an integer amount of such bytes.

The offset moves the memory address pointer register from where you are to a new address.  The new address is calculated as the sum of the current address plus the given amount expressed in the offset.  By using offsets declared as an integer amount of bytes, your new offset may point at any address location within the reach of the offset.  In order to make it practical for you to use another definition of the offset, the manufacturer of the microprocessor would be compelled to add specific instructions for each type of offset.  For example, instead of "LW" for load word, you could choose from "LW16", "LW32", "LW64" or other adequate instruction that would clearly indicate the number of bits employed by the elements of your data array.  But simply using "LW" would leave the question up in the air as regarding the nature of the word (16, 32, 64?) used by different manufacturers, forcing you to carefully read the datasheets of the different microprocessors that you have to handle.

It boils down to compatibility between different microprocessors and the engineering choices that need to be made when designing the architecture of a microprocessor.

(Please, pardon me if you find any mistyped characters).

Answer (score -1):

To clarify the reason why a byte is used to describe the offset to a base address it is necessary to know a bit of history.

Many years ago, there were computers whose memory was made up of twelve (12) bits. In these computers, a printable character employed six (6) bits but lacked lowercase letters.  Please refer to the following link for some examples.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-bit_computing

Then came ASCII which used seven (7) bits to represent a character from the ASCII Table, including lowercase and uppercase letters (a boon for word processors).  In order to detect a single bit change during transmission, a parity bit was added, making it necessary to send eight (8) bits per character.

So, the eight (8) bit byte seemed the logical way to go.  New digital computers used the eight (8) bit byte for storage and, consequently, the arithmetic and logic unit was made to work with bytes of eight (8) bits.

Since an byte made of eight (8) bits can store unsigned integers from 0 to 255, or signed integers (in one's complement notation) from 0 up to 127 in the positive side and -1 down to -128 in the negative side, there was a clear need for something bigger than a byte in order to be able to store larger numbers.  That something is a word.  Please refer to the following links for further information.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Words

A word can be made of sixteen (16) bits, thirty two (32) bits, sixty four (64) bits and other sizes as well. That is why you will see such things as short word, long word, double word, quad word and other variants.

So, if there is no clear definition of exactly how many bits are needed to compose a "word", the best way to define the offset to a base address is the use of the universally accepted byte made of eight (8) bits.  By using bytes for the offset you cannot go wrong because the size of the byte does not depend on the manufacturer of the microprocessor, whereas the size of the "word" depends exclusively on the meaning given to it by the manufacturer of the microprocessor.

By the way, when storing the bytes that make up your "word", you will start by storing the least significant byte of your word in the base address when you employ "little endian" or LE mode.  Otherwise, you will start by storing the most significant byte of your word in the base address when you employ "big endian" or BE mode.

When transmitting data over a channel used for serial communications between digital systems, you may use the little endian mode and send the least significant bit in the first place, and the most significant bit in the last place.  Otherwise, you may use the big endian mode and send the most significant bit in the first place, and the least significant bit in the last place.

In order to avoid mixing the order of the bits of a "word", you and any other user of the system shall abide to the exact procedure set forth by the method that was chosen for its storage or transmission over a channel used for serial communications.

Comment: I have downvoted because, respectfully, this doesn't answer the question which is about unscaled offsets; additionally some of your statements are wrong.   Contrary to "univesrally accepted", there are plenty of older texts that use "byte" to mean "appropriate number of bits", which we normally use "word" for nowadays. (Octet *is* universally accepted.)  "Word" isn't unclear, as you say, is is flexible, except when defined in a certain context. (So we can write: "choose an appropriate word size for the following ALU").  Further,  ASCII was originally without lowercase.